# From a bag of n balls, with c colours, and d draws count how many variations are possible?

Tags: combinatorics, challenge-community

First, the objective is not to use formulas for combinations, or permutations.
The objective is to use loops(for, while, etc.) to make *Mathematica* count the number of possible variations/sequences of the following situation:

Let's assume we have a bag with $n$ balls, with $c$ different colours, and $d$ draws from the bag. There is no replacement, and you can consider separately the case when the order is important, and when it's not.

For this question, I appreciate readability more than efficiency.

Edit: $n=\sum_{i=1}^c n_i$, where $n_i$ is the number of balls for a determined i-th colour.  The user should also be able to choose the $n_i$'s

Comment: Do you know how many balls there are of each colour?

Comment: @mikado the user should have the option of also determining their number.

Comment: See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Combination as a first reading to this end. Good luck!

Comment: @user64494 that's not the point of this challenge. ;)

Comment: This is really not a Mathematica question. Looking for an algorithm is not the same as requesting help with a specific implementation in a specific programming language.

Comment: @DanielLichtblau I know that... I was just wondering if something like a challenge to the community with a question like this could be started, and people would adhere. If it's completely outside the scope, so be it. You can close it, it's ok.

Answer (score 2):

EDITED: important modification

I have no idea if the logic is sound and I am likely cheating, but there is some counting going on! For the example given, I get 188 possibilities.

````
(* List representing the content of the bag (i.e number for each \
color of balls) *)
contentOfBag = {2, 4, 6, 7};

(* We get total number of balls n from the sum of these colored balls \
*)
n = Total[contentOfBag];

(* number of draw from which we get d (cannot exceed n) *)
draw = 8;
d = Min[draw, n];

(* We permute the the contentOfBags fror later comparison *)

perm = Permutations[contentOfBag];

(* The number of colors *)
c = Length[contentOfBag];

(* Possible combinations of number of balls of different colors in \
the balls drawn 
  For example, one such combination may tellus that from 8 balls \
drawn, 7 where of one color, and 1 of another color (it does not tell \
us the actual colors)
*)  
ip = IntegerPartitions[d, {c}, Table[i, {i, 0, Max[contentOfBag]}]];

(* This compares the above result with the permutations of the actual \
values in contentOfBags. We then count those where there are enough \
balls of a particular color to meet the demand *) 
count = 0;
j = 1;
While[j <= Length[ip],
 k = 1;
 While[k <= Length[perm],
  m = 1;
  valid = Table[False, c];
  While[m <= c,
   If[perm[[k]][[m]] >= ip[[j]][[m]], valid[[m]] = True];
   m++;
   ];
  If[valid == Table[True, c], count++];
  k++;
  ];
 j++;
 ]
count
```
````